# JQuery Datepicker - limit TIME options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker element with date and time. It is used to book an event for certain date and time. I want to restrict date and time options, so an event can be booked only on available time slots.

I can restrict certain dates with *beforeShowDay* option, but the function accepts date part only, hence I can't use this function to limit available time options.

How can I limit time values of a datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this addon : [trentrichardson.com](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) or [Github link](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)

jQueryUI datepicker does not have a `timepicker` included in it.

```
$('#rest_example_1').timepicker({
  hourMin: 8,
  hourMax: 16
});
```